# How to get yahoo calender events through Yahoo OAuth integration in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, oauth, yahoo-api

I am using this link: https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc for login in yahoo account.

In this code i am providing credentials of yahoo account but iam not getting the access token it gives message

To complete sharing of yahoo! info with xxxx, enter code xxxx into xxxx

So, I am not getting that where I should enter this code? And how will it redirect to my application.

Any help will be appreciated.